# Set array elements as options using setchoicevalues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, multiple-choice

This is my first post! :)

I'm trying to do the following:

There is an event, and I have to put available hours in what people can join and number of persons can join in each option.
Ex:

```
5/5 11:00-12:00 available 2 places.
5/5 12:00-13:00 full (10/10 joined)
5/5 13:00-14:00 available 6 places...
```

I decided to create a spreadsheet with this:
A row: event date-time;
B row: people joined;
C row: limit.

When a person send a form, the B row increases in 1, and the options are updated with the new values.

```
Before:
5/5 11:00-12:00 available 2 places.
5/5 12:00-13:00 full (10/10 joined)
**5/5 13:00-14:00 available 6 places.**

Mr A joins to 3rd course.

After

5/5 11:00-12:00 available 2 places.
5/5 12:00-13:00 full (10/10 joined)
**5/5 13:00-14:00 available 5 places.**
```

When that occurs, the options are updated doing the following:

```
//Code what updates the number in the sheet//
//Now we have to re-set the options//
var range=sheet.getRange("A1:C20"); //Take the new values
var options=[];
for (var i=0; i<range.length; i++)
if (conditions) options.push(range[i][0]); //charges the options
```

And finally set the output:

```
    var multiplechoice=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE[0].
asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues([options[0],options[1],...,options[19]]);
```

The code works property, but the problem is the last line: Is not convenient in terms of flexibility. In case of recycle the code o add more options I will have to rewrite that.

I want to do just this:

```
    var multiplechoice=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[0].
asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues([options]);
```

I tried to just do that (.setChoiceValues([options])) but the result is all the array in just one option. I need to the script recognizes each element of options as a different elements.

But I dont know the way. Y realized that there were a FormApp function what helps me with that, but after search a lot I didnt find the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets around `options`, so it looks like this `setChoiceValues(options)` and it should work.

The setChoiceValues() method expects a one-dimensional array of strings, but with the squared brackets you're giving it a two-dimensional array, because `options` on itself is already an array.